# Export data from Joomla! db and import into Ownlcoud db

Tags: mysql, joomla

I am attempting to export data from a joomla MySQL database and import it into a owncloud MySQL database.

Joomla! db table is xxx_users, columns required for export are: 
username, password.

Ownlcloud db table is xxx_users, columns required for import are: 
uid(username), password.

the Owncloud password encryption is slightly different to Joomla!, in that it has a '1|' prefix to the password, I dont know how to achieve this.

I have an export and import script, but needs a little work.

This is to be used with a cron job, if the user exists in the Owncloud db, details will be overwritten.

export.php

```
<?php
//ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
$mysqlDatabaseName ='db1';
$mysqlUserName ='db1owner';
$mysqlHostName ='db1.mywebhost.net';
$mysqlExportPath ='db1backup.sql';

//DONT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p'     .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'
> ~/' .$mysqlExportPath;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
case 0:
echo 'Database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> successfully exported to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
break;
case 1:
echo 'There was a warning during the export of <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName   .'</b> to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
break;
case 2:
echo 'There was an error during export. Please check your values:<br/><br/>    <table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td>   </tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr>   <td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN </b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:   </td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr></table>';
break;
}
?>
```

import.php

```
<?php
//ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
$mysqlDatabaseName ='db2';
$mysqlUserName ='db2owner';
$mysqlPassword ='Password';
$mysqlHostName ='db2.mywebhost.net';
$mysqlImportFilename ='db1backup.sql';

//DONT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysql -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' < ' .$mysqlImportFilename;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
case 0:
echo 'Import file <b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b> successfully imported to     database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b>';
break;
case 1:
echo 'There was an error during import. Please make sure the import file is     saved in the same folder as this script and check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Import Filename:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b></td></tr></table>';
break;
}
?>
```

Comment: This sounds like an interesting project! Do let us know if you happen to have a question!

Comment: thanks, the last part is the difficult bit for me, pre-pending a hash to the password prior to import into Owncloud db.